# Servlet + tomcat + mysql

Tags: servlet

на сервер (*tomcat*) поступают запросы

```
{host}?method=getb&uid={account}&providerid={providers name}
```

пример:

```
http://192.168.1.100/api/balans.php?method=delb&uid=9288680357&providerid=megafon
```

Необходимо, чтобы сервлет обработал данный запрос.

1. как получить данный запрос и прочитать эти параметры?
2. обработка БД (подкл, редактирование)?

В *java* новичок (можно сказать чайник), прошу более подробнее объяснять, что и как делать.

Comment: request.getParameter("name"), а для базы jdbc наверное.

Comment: а есть какой либо пример ....для более визульной наглядности

Comment: @maximus116 Если с английским языком дружите, то прочтите книгу "Java EE Development with Eclipse Second Edition". Там по Вашей теме все расписано подробно.

Answer (score 1):

Пример простого сервлета, который выводит в консоль переданные параметры GET-запроса.

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

@WebServlet("/api/balans")
public class BalanceServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Выводим в консоль.
    System.out.println(req.getQueryString());

    // Выводим на html-страницу.
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Balance</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<div>" + req.getQueryString() + "</div>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");

  }
}
```

Comment: запускаю данный пример ....у меня только html страница открывается наверно  из за этого "System.out.println(req.getQueryString());"  А как вывести параметры в HTML документ ??

Comment: @maximus116, дополнил ответ. Почитайте основы написания сервлетов, тогда сразу все станет понятно. На эту тему есть много примеров.